# How to use AutoHotkey to copy a particular password?

Tags: autohotkey, keepass

I would like to copy a password (i.e password only from an entry) from keepass using AutoHotkey. Is this possible?

I am quite sure, the keepass entry can be selected using a shortcut as below, but after selecting the entry I wanted to press CTRL+C so that my clipboard will contain the password. So how can we automate that CTRL+C step?

```
^+4::Run, "C:\Program Files (x86)\KeePass Password Safe 2\KeePass.exe" -uuid:EF52D477F6986248B3234490FF9EB8EA
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RunWait instead of Run, add a little sleep, then issue the
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

I don't use KeePass and can't test, but it might look something like this:

```
^+4::
RunWait, "C:\Program Files (x86)\KeePass Password Safe 2\KeePass.exe" -uuid:EF52D477F6986248B3234490FF9EB8EA
Sleep, 100
Send, ^c
Return
```

Comment: If the above program-call (that I can't test) is correct, the problem might be the that the focus is on the wrong window after it terminates. What exactly happens after this is run, and where is the focus. A screenshot might be useful.

Comment: Add to the script the [WinHide](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinHide.htm) command after the Send, and it should return to the traybar.

Comment: Tried WinHide after the send, but it doesn't seem to work.. The screen remains maximized... I tried sending ALT+F4 keys to close the windows so that it goes back to tray. Both doesn't seem to work.. Any idea, if any syntax is incorrect? https://dpaste.org/8F4s

Comment: What does WinMinimize do? KeePass might have a config param for minimizing to the tray.

Comment: No actions are happening with WinMinimize also.. Manually pressing ALT+F4 closing the application and allowing it to goto the tray.. But why are we not able to send ALT+F4 in our script ? Any thoughts?

Comment: Certainly: `Send, !{F4}`